# SSRS Migration from 2008R2 to 2017 Error RSPortal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2017

I was migrating our reporting services from the version 2008R2 to the version 2017 restoring the db and all seems to work fine unless for some report for which I cannot open the subscriptions page.

For those report every time I enter in the report subscriptions page from the web view I get this error
"Something went wrong. Please try again later. "

If I go in the log from the RSPortal File I see this error:

```
ERROR: OData exception occurred: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 18.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.ODataExtensions.ParameterValueExtensions.FormatAsISO8601Date(String date, String culture)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.ODataExtensions.ParameterValueExtensions.ToWebApiReportParameterValue(ParameterValue parameterValue, ReportParameterType reportParameterType, String culture)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.ODataExtensions.SubscriptionExtensions.ToReportPameterList(SubscriptionImpl librarySubscription, Dictionary`2 parameterTypes, String culture)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.ODataExtensions.SubscriptionExtensions.ToWebApiModel(SubscriptionImpl librarySubscription, Dictionary`2 parameterTypes, SubscriptionProperties properties)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve it? I thought was something related to the CultureInfo value but I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably could be helpful for someone in the future so I will indicate the steps I took to solve this issue:
This issue was due to a data type mismatching on one parameter for a few subscriptions.
Seems that the error handling has changed in the time with Microsoft in fact, after I found the subscriptions that were having problems I tried to open them in the old environment and I have got this error:

```
“The Value provided for the report parameter “YourDate’ is not valid for it is type (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)”
```

What I did so was to delete these subscriptions with the error in the new Reporting Server environment and finally the web view worked fine